# In John Scalzi's "The Human Division," who did Michael Washington work for?

Tags: old-mans-war

In chapter 4 (["A Voice in the Wilderness"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1542877)) in John Scalzi's [*The Human Division,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Division) the venal talk-radio host Albert Birnbaum is hired (by someone calling himself Michael Washington) to promote the virtues of the Colonial Union.

> At the end of the story, Washington kills Birnbaum, in such a way that no-one will know who did it.

Why? What was that about? Who does Washington work for, the Colonial Union or

> Equilibrium?